# To find New error in server logs that was not present in logs in the past one week

Tags: logging, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation

I am looking to trigger an alert in splunk if a new error is there in server logs. New error is an error/s that was not present in server logs in the past one week. I have index for logs index=Serverlogs1.

Please help!

Comment: Could you be more specific, please?  What kind of anomaly are you looking for?  In what kind of data?

Comment: I am looking to trigger an alert in splunk if a new error is there in server logs. New error is an error/s that was not present in server logs in the past one week. I have index for logs index=Serverlogs1.

Please help!

Comment: What have you already tried? What does the data look like? How do you determine "new"? Is it *anywhere* in the last week? Only on *one endpoint*? Something else?

Comment: My goal is to scan splunk logs for all errors in stack trace for past one week (excluding today) and find any anomaly/ new errors in past 24 hours.

Most of the times "message" field have stack trace.

But, for same error  in "message" field  profileid /jsession fields should be ignored.

On using below query, then  for same error, if jsessionid and profile are different it shows that also  as an anomaly (which is not what I expected)

 "index=serverlogs1 log_level=error  | anomalydetection action=filter message  "

Answer (score 0):

Finding something that has not been seen in some time requires searching all of the data over that period so be prepared for slow performance.  It will help if you can be specific about the criteria for a "new" event.  Start with this search.  Replace `_raw` with specific fields, if possible.

```
index=serverlogs1 earliest=-1w
| stats count by _raw
| where count = 1
```

Comment: My goal is to scan splunk logs for all errors in stack trace for past one week (excluding today) and find any anomaly/ new errors in past 24 hours.

Most of the times "message" field have stack trace.

But, for same error  in "message" field  profileid /jsession fields should be ignored.

On using below query, then  for same error, if jsessionid and profile are different it shows that also  as an anomaly (which is not what I expected)

 "index=serverlogs1 log_level=error  | anomalydetection action=filter message  "